# If PHP prepare statement fails once subsequent prepares also fail?

Tags: php, mysqli

Two functions here: http://pastebin.com/CNLBBMZ2 (with intentional error on line 11)
Here is how it's called: http://pastebin.com/VBxvE4D9

I'm having trouble getting my second function to prepare properly after my first prepare fails. I'm using mysqli prepared statements.

For simplicity, let's say I have two boolean functions.

The first function called upon a user form submit creates a record in my database. The second function lists all the records in the database and is called each time the page is loaded regardless of user input.

Here is part of the first function

```
//connect to database
    $dbh = db_connect();

//Transaction to create all the records necessary for this house
    $dbh->autocommit(FALSE);

// 1. query to insert a new house table record
    if ( $stmt_create_house = $dbh->prepare("
            INSERT INTO house (nickname, dateCreated, userID)
            VALUES ( ? , ? , ?)
        ")) {
    //bind param
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $stmt_create_house->bind_param( 'sss', $_POST['house-nickname'], $today, $_SESSION['user_id'] );
    } else {
        $dbh->close(); 
        $create_error_message = "The query to create a new house record was malformed.";
        return FALSE; //jumps out of the function
    }
... rest of function
```

If I purposely fail the first prepare statement in the first function, the second completely unrelated function will fail as well. I purposely fail the first statement by typing in a wrong column name or otherwise malformed it just to test.

I want the second function to be able to still pull records from the database even though the first statement failed for whatever reason. Here is the section of code in my second function. This If statement fails when the first prepare statement fails.

```
//connect to database
    $dbh = db_connect();
if ( $stmt_get_houses = $dbh->prepare("
            SELECT houseID, nickname, dateCreated
            FROM house
            WHERE userID = ?
        ")) {
```

I can't figure out why failing the prepare in the function affects the second function. I close the $dbh each time I encouter an error. Do I have to clear an error buffer on the $dbh connection even if I close it?

Comment: return FALSE; kills the rest of the code from executing?

Comment: Yes return false exits that function first function.

Comment: Can you please post the full file contents? Or at least both functions.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of the code  http://pastebin.com/CNLBBMZ2

Comment: Can you post how you're calling both of the functions sequentially?

Comment: This is how they are called: http://pastebin.com/VBxvE4D9

Comment: This might be killing the second call:             //call function to create a new house
            $_SESSION['create_success'] = build_a_house($create_error_message);

            if ( $_SESSION['create_success'] ) {
                //Redirect back to this page.
                //This prevents page refresh from adding another house to database.
                header("Location:houses-and-settings.php");
                exit();
            }

Comment: The second funtion IS getting called, it's just returning the echo statement on line 145 telling me the prepare statement failed and that the query was malformed. But if I go to the page without submitting, it displays the houses just fine!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72721/discussion-between-vladimir-ramik-and-s-mason).